# How can I define a class in multi file(or module) in python

Tags: python, class

So I want to define a Class `A` 
looks like:

in `a.py`:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       pass

   def some_method_in_a(self):
       pass
```

and now I want define some additional methods in `b.py`. looks like:

```
continue define class A:
def some_method_in_b_but_bellows_classA(self):
    pass
```

So are there any simple methods to do this?

Comment: What does 'continue define' means here? Adding some new methods to the old class? Overriding some attributes?

Comment: Why not define them in sub classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would typically accomplish this using [inheritance.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)

You define general classes which your 'A' class inherits attributes or methods from. Something like:

/b.py:

```
class generalObjectLikeA:
    def some_method_in_b_but_bellows_classA(self):
        pass
```

/a.py:

```
class A(b.generalObjectLikeA):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def some_method_in_a(self):
        pass
```

Comment: as a side note: camelCase is considered 'unpythonic', but I like it.

Comment: camelCase is only unpythonic for variable and function/method names. It's the recommended convention for class names.

Comment: @chepner CamelCase is not camelCase

Comment: Good point. I glossed over the (lack of a) initial capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use inheritance for some reasons(like monkey patch), functions and classes are normal objects in python, you can change them dynamiclly.

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()

def bar(self):
    print id(self)

A.foo = bar
a.foo()
b = A()
b.foo()
```

References:

[Monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)

[Monkeypatching For Humans](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/monkeypatching-for-humans.html)